# Can I inject a Function into an HTML String?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to inject a function into a map popup.  This is an Angular 8 project using a service TypeScript file to implement Leaflet open source mapping library.  When clicking on a pinned location on the map, I want the tooltip/popup that appears to contain the street address of the location and include a linked function within the dialog.  All of this must be contained in a string representation, and I've been able to get everything in place except for the function itself.  Below is an example of how I'm trying to inject the function (please disregard the single quotes, they are only there to ensure the ticks are displayed):

`` '`<div style="font-size: 0.875rem; font-weight: 500; line-height: normal; letter-spacing: 0.3px; color: #0e1112;">${geotags[j].locationAddress}</div><div id="index-${j}" class="pt-3" style="font-size: 0.875rem; line-height: 1.14; color: #096fec;" onclick="${desiredFunctionToRun}">DETAILS</div>`' ``

I have tried clicking the 'DETAILS' button, with no result from the function.  The literal code of the function shows up in the browser's element, instead of the native code:

[image: Function represented as a literal string in browser]

I have tried using `(click)="${desiredFunctionToRun}`, as well as with and without `()` on the end of the function name (parentheses on the end causes the function to run for each pinned item upon initialization of the view; not desired at all).   Unfortunately, I'm not trying to simply navigate to another view, but rather process some specific data about the clicked pinned address.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  Can you inject a function into a string element that can be read as native code by the browser?

Comment: You don't want to use the `onclick` handler, because that is outside the `angular` scope. If you want the output of the function, try `(click)="desiredFunctionToRun()"`.

Comment: The Head Rush - If you notice, I say that I tried that with no luck.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if any library let you inject runnable code via a string. Even if they did, you would have to read up on what syntax you need to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot inject the function into the HTML template like you are currently using on Angular. the way you can do that you use `(click)="methodName()"` for the html template then on the .ts file you implement `methodName()` method with whatever function that you want

Comment: I see you told @TheHeadRush that you tried `(click)="desiredFucntionToRun()"` but have you placed a breakpoint in that function when you have it running to see if it's actually doing anything? If it's a popup (akin to something like google maps) I feel like you may be needing to add that function to the window object.

Comment: My idea is to try what i suggested, which is not what you say you tried. If you have the shown `desiredFunctionToRun` method in the component, you will see the output to console. What won't work is trying to use a function literal in the template.